# How to Map Partial Elements in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list of integers:

```
val mylist = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

What I want to do is to map the element which are even numbers in mylist, and multiply them by 2.

Maybe the code should be:

```
mylist.map{ case x%2==2 => x*2 }
```

I expect the result to be List(4, 8) but it's not. What is the correct code?

I know I could realize this function by using filter + map

```
a.filter(_%2 == 0).map(_*2)
```

but is there some way to realize this function by only using map()?

Comment: This question doesn't look related to apache-spark. Why the tag?

Comment: I meet the same problem in spark 's map() function of RDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` does not reduce number of elements in transformation. 
`filter + map` is right approach.

But if single method is needed, use `collect`:

```
mylist.collect{ case x if x % 2 == 0 => 2 * x }
```

**Edit:**

`withFilter + map` is more efficient than `filter + map` (as `withFilter` does not create intermediate collection, i.e. it works lazily):

```
mylist.withFilter(_ % 2 == 0).map(_ * 2)
```

which is same as `for` :

```
for { e <- mylist if (e % 2 == 0) } yield 2 * e
```

Comment: `collect` is probably the best choice, but you could use `withFilter` to pipeline; or implicitly use `withFilter` via a for comprehension.

Comment: Could you give a code example about withFilter? thank you :-)